# Preserving inclusions closed irreducible sets in quasi-affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Y$ be a quasi-affine variety and $Z_1 \subset Z_2$ be closed irreducible subsets of $Y$. I am trying to check that the inclusion ${\overline{Z_1}} \subset {\overline{Z_2}}$ is proper.

Here $Y \subseteq Z({\mathfrak{p}})$ is an open subset in ${\mathbb{A}}^n(k)$ (with ${\mathfrak{p}}$ prime). Now $Z_1 = C_1 \cap Y, Z_2 = C_2 \cap Y$ with $C_1, C_2$ closed in $Z({\mathfrak{p}})$ (and hence must be in ${\mathbb{A}}^n(k)$ as well). We can also choose these so that $C_1 \subset C_2$. However, in general, the closure doesn't respect intersection of sets (for instance take open intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ in ${\mathbb{R}}$).

Does irreducibility plays a role here?

Comment: You're assuming that $Z_1\subset Z_2$ is proper, right? Hint: where do all the points in $\overline{Z_i}\setminus Z_i$ live?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kreiser: $Z_1 \subsetneq Z_2$ implies the choice $C_1 \subsetneq C_2$ is possible. Then $(Y \setminus C_1) \cap C_2 \neq \emptyset$. For any $x \in (Y \setminus C_1) \cap C_2$ we have $Y \setminus C_1$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $x \in C_2 \cap Y \subseteq {\overline{C_2 \cap Y}}$. In case ${\overline{C_2 \cap Y}} = {\overline{C_1 \cap Y}}$, we must have $(C_1 \cap Y) \cap (Y \setminus C_1) \neq \emptyset$, which is absurd.

Comment: In simpler terms, since we assumed $Z_1\subsetneq Z_2$, there is some point $x\in Z_2\setminus Z_1$ (in particular, this means $x\in Y$). We also have that $Z_i= Y\cap C_i$ for some closed $C_i$. As $\overline{Z_i}\subset C_i$ and $Z_i\subset \overline{Z_i}$, we have that $\overline{Z_i}\cap Y=Z_i$. So $x$ is in $\overline{Z_2}$ but not $\overline{Z_1}$, as if it were, then it would necessarily be in $Z_1$, which is a contradiction. Nothing was used here except closedness of $Z_i$ in the subspace topology on $U$ and the properness of the inclusion..